# Two Dimensional Self-Reciprocal BravaisLattice

Tags: condensed-matter, atoms, crystals, lattice-model

I've been reading *Quantum States of Atoms Molecules and Solids* by Morrison et al. for a condensed matter course. They make the claim that all 2D Bravais lattices are self-reciprocal, but I'm having difficulty picturing that or preferably rigorously proving it.

I know I could write the lattice vector as $ R = k_1 \vec{a} + k_2 \vec{b}$ and then the corresponding reciprocal lattice would be $n_1 \vec{A} + n_2 \vec{B}$ where the vectors satisfy $ 2\pi \delta_{ij} $.

I don't actually know to calculate the reciprocal lattice for only 2D though? They gave an example for the square lattice where they introduced a orthongonal third vector, but I would like to do it more general than this.

Does anyone have a nice proof for why this is true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/340862/37496

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about why the new form preserves the geometry though. That's why I posted a new question

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "the new form preserves the geometry"

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{a}_1$, $\mathbf{a}_2$ be the lattice vectors a two-dimensional Bravais lattice, let
\begin{align}
R = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
be the orthogonal matrix rotating by $\pi/2$ in two dimensions, and let $\epsilon^{ij}$ be the antisymmetric symbol in two dimensions. From Emilio Pisanty's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/340862/37496), the reciprocal lattice vectors for a two-dimensional Bravais lattice have components
\begin{align}
b_{1i} &= \frac{1}{\epsilon^{kl} a_{1k}a_{2l}}R_{ij}a_{2j}\\
b_{2i} &= -\frac{1}{\epsilon^{kl} a_{1k}a_{2l}}R_{ij}a_{2j}.\\
\end{align}
in Einstein notation. We observe directly that the $\mathbf{b}_i$ are scalar multiples of the original lattice vectors (rotated by $\pi/2$).